# What does the graph of $\sin^2 x$ look like?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

When solving trig equations, sometimes it comes out as a hidden quadratic, like this:

$2\sin^2x-5\sin x+2=0$

Obviously it is possible to factorise and solve for $\sin x$.

I understand graph transformations so $-\sin x$ is an inverted sine graph, so what would $\sin^2x$ look like? As the sine function itself is being raised to the power $2$.

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%29%5E2&x=0&y=0

Comment: $\sin^2 x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$.

Comment: You can obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$ by typing, respectively, \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, and \cot x when you are in math mode.

Comment: @darthvader Why don't you use  https://www.desmos.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A neat way to think of this is by noticing that

$$
\cos(2a) = 1 - 2\sin^2(a)
$$

Hence,

$$
\sin^2(a) = \frac{1 - \cos(2a)}{2}
$$

So, it's the graph of $\cos(a)$ flipped, "sped up" by a factor of 2, raised up by 1 unit above the $y$-axis, and then finally shrunk by a factor of $2$ along the $y$-axis.

[WolframAlpha plot for reference](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%5E2+x)

Comment: The graph of $sinx$ can be generated using phasors. (See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KZDr_vZIUI for reference). Can the graph of $sin^2x$ be generated in a similar way?

Comment: Yes, you can. In fact, plot $1 - \cos(2a)\2$ and think of the oscillation of a point only along the y-axis as it moves along the x-axis. That is what the phasor will look like with respect to time in some sense

Answer (score 0):

1. If the sine value is negative than the square of it is positive.
2. Since sine is periodic in 0 to pi, its square is also periodic but with period pi.
3. Also since sine value lies from $-1$ to $1$ its square lies from $0$ to $1$
4. Square of a number between 0 and 1 will be still lesser than the number.